# how to ignore a ' char in php

Tags: php, sql

I want to have a string with the char ' in it, without having it closing the string:

```
$title = "google";
$link = "www.google.com";
$val_str = "'" . $title . "'," . $link . "'";
$query = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (title,link) . VALUES (" . $val_str . ")";
```

so that `$val_str` will have: `'google', 'www.google.com'`
in it.

how can i do it?

Comment: That is a) basic PHP string material: http://php.net/string (see about escape sequences) but more importantly b) Use prepared statements to build your SQL query. Then you don't need to care about that which is non-trivial. You find an example with PDO here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: are you using `mysql` or `mysqli` or `pdo` ? all three has functions to escape `'` and `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a backslash to escape the `'` character in your string:

```
echo 'Hello: "I\'ll be back"';
```

Comment: This is technically correct, but as soon as the data becomes a variable, you need `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 0):

Escape it with a `\`.

i.e. `\'google.com\'`

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (title,link) VALUES ('$title', '$link')";
```

If `$title` and `$link` is not under your control, then you need to escape them.